# Aurelia on Heroku, JSPM's system.js "blocked due to MIME type mismatch"

Tags: javascript, html, heroku, aurelia, jspm

I'm trying to host a simple (Typescript) Aurelia app on Heroku with a very simple Express server, but when I spin it up I get the following error in Firefox:

> The resource from
>   “https://ub-edis.herokuapp.com/jspm_packages/system.js” was blocked
>   due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

and then all sorts of subsequent errors because the code obviously can't resolve `System`.

Running this code locally works perfectly well.  Since I'm not sure how to configure Heroku to install my JSPM and Typings dependencies, I'm using dropbox to upload my repo.  So I just copy and pasted my whole project directory over (I know this isn't ideal, but I'm just a newby trying to get this thing to work with minimal effort, not to produce production code).  If I look under the Sources tab in the Chrome dev tools it finds my config.js correctly, so I don't think I'm getting the error because it can't find system.js.

This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>EDIS</title>
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm a little out of my depth with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I open your URL, I get a 404 on https://ub-edis.herokuapp.com/jspm_packages/system.js
Can you check if it really exists in your jspm_packages directory?

Comment: The problem was indeed due to the jspm_packages directory being absent.  I didn't realize until reading further that Heroku would read the .gitignore file and not upload those elements, even though they were in the linked Dropbox directory.  After deleting the .gitignore and resyncing, it worked as intended.  Thanks for pointing me that direction!